How to hide/disable processing time message?
I am using Gradio Blocks. Whenever the user sends a prompt, a spinner and a processing runtime message are shown.
There is a show_progress setting in the submit method but it allows to hide both the runtime message and the spinner. I want to show the spinner but not the runtime message.
How do I remove it? I am assuming via a CSS passed to blocks, eg
with gr.Blocks(css="<whatever that is>") as demo

What would that css be? Or if not using CSS, is there another way?
Thanks!
EDIT: I've figured it out, see my answer below.

Through trial and error I've found that this works:
gr.Blocks(css=".progress-text { display: none !important; })"

